# FLUTTER: How to add data in an existing collection in firestore

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add more data in an existing collection in my firestore db 
[This is my db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GnkP.jpg) 
So i wanted to add the following inside it like this 
Location: 
Work:
How can i add them inside my users collection without the existing ones changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the `add` function : 
`Firestore.instance.collection('users').add({/* map of data */});`
it will add your `document` with a random id

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create a new document within a collection.

```
Firestore.instance.collection('users').document('Location').setData(data);
```

Above is Dart code for accomplishing this. That line will add a new document to the 'users' collection.

More info on the Cloud Firestore plugin for Flutter can be found here.
https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pre-created document, then you can use Firestore's `updateData` function

```
Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(uid).updateData({"location":"work"});
```

You can also use `setData` if you want it to create a document if a document doesn't already exist.